# How to rename wget-downloaded files sequentially?

Tags: image, bash, curl, rename, wget

Let's say I am downloading image files from a website with wget.

`wget -H -p -w 2 -nd -nc -A jpg,jpeg -R gif "forum.foo.com/showthread.php?t=12345"`

there are 20 images in that page.. when downloaded, the images are saved as their original file names.

I want to rename the first image downloaded by wget as 
`001-original_filename.jpg`, the second one as `002-original_filename.jpg`, and so on..

What to do? Is bash or curl needed for this?

Note: I am on windows.

Comment: May be you should rename after download using time stamp...

Comment: @MaheshKharvi The downloaded files' time stamps are not the time of downloads, their time stamps are the original as in the server..

Comment: You can use `ls -crt` to sort with modification date

Answer (score 0):

If you have bash installed, after files downloaded, run this.

```
i=1
ls -crt | while read file; do
   newfile=$(printf "%.3d-%s\n" $i "$file")
   mv "$file" "$newfile"
   i=$((i+1))
done
```

ls -crt : list files using creation date, reverse order using time stamp.

.3d in printf will precision number to 3 digit